# Is there a way to intercept data on a particular port?

Tags: java

I would like to read all the data that comes via port 8080 even if my application is not the one who requested it.
e.g on google chrome, I type www.google.com, I press enter and the incoming packets are read by my app (and google chrome).

is there a way to do this?

Comment: In FF, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/, or Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) or NetTool (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nettool/). Hope this is what you were after...

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking for.  Do you want to intercept all traffic to local web browsers?  Or, build a web server?  Maybe a more complete description of what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: sorry Gus, I want to intercept all traffic to local web browsers

Comment: You can configure Fiddler as a proxy, which will do what you want, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using a [PCAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) (Packet CAPture) library such as [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/).